# Win32 ReadFile timeout takes 25ms more then expected

Tags: c#, c++, windows, serial-port

**What I am trying to do:**

I am writting a C# app calling ReadFile from a dll. I am reading from a serial COM port;

I would like to set the timeout the ReadFile function to a fixed value of Nms.

**The problem:**

When I set the constant timeout to a fixed Nms, it seems to take about N+25ms.

```
timeout=1ms -> actual time=31ms  
timeout=10ms -> actual time=31ms  
timeout=20ms -> actual time=46ms  
timeout=100ms -> actual time=125ms
```

**Details:**

Code for configuring the timeouts:

```
config_timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
config_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = value;
config_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
```

How I am measuring the time:

```
public int read(byte[] data, int offset, int len)
{
    lock (lock_port) 
    {
        var watch_read = new Stopwatch();
        watch_read.Start();
        var result = port_read(handle, data, (uint)offset, (uint)len);
        watch_read.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"read in={watch_read.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unmanaged code I am calling:

```
int port_read(HANDLE port, uint8_t *data, unsigned int offset, unsigned int len)
{
    DWORD total = 0;
    DWORD read = 0;
    BOOL status;

    // read byte
    status = ReadFile(port, data + read + offset, len - read, &read, NULL);

    if (FALSE == status) {
        return 0;
    }   

    return read;
}
```

The call stack should be:
read > port_read > ReadFile
(a C# function calling a C++ function calling ReadFile)

I am also calling WriteFile from C# from a different thread, but I use a `lock() {}` for both C# functions calling ReadFile, WriteFile.
But I write virtually nothing, and the write timeout does not affect the read timeout.

The ReadFile call will be shorter if all bytes are read.

How can I make the ReadFile call timeout after Nms (the set constant timeout)? In other words, where is the added 25ms comming from and how can I remove this additional delay?

Comment: Calling functions isn't free, there's always some overhead. Going from managed to unmanaged code is probably more expensive than managed to managed calls, but you're not telling us those details so we can't tell if that's a factor. And without a [mcve] there's no way of knowing if there are other possible factors.

Comment: The 25ms is likely to be the overhead associated with accessing the port behind the scenes - which is why it's consistent across the different examples you provided

Comment: _"...Time-out intervals are measured relative to the system clock, and the accuracy of the time-out measurement is limited by the granularity of the system clock. As a result, a time-out can occur between one system clock tick earlier and one tick later than the specified time-out interval, depending on where exactly the start and end times of this interval fall between system clock ticks. ..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I don't think it's managed to unmanaged, it's user-mode to kernel-mode. The process will be descheduled and rescheduled. That's not necessarily expensive, but if another process gets a CPU timeslice then a 25 ms delay is perfectly sane

Comment: Interresting point @MSalters. But shoud it be this consistent, because it is like 46-47ms, it does not varry much?

Comment: When you talking about any I/O operation to hardware over a serial port, 25ms is hardly an unexpected delay

Comment: @Martin well that +25 is the time it takes to timeout, not to receive a reply

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It all results in the same regardless of whether it's CLI or unmanaged - privileged code will need to run to access the serial port via the driver

Comment: Windows simply isn't a real-time OS. Random timing variation in that sort of order is expected, particularly when you're doing things like context-switching, I/O, etc. Trying to eliminate this order of variation is a fool's errand

Comment: @Martin: A serial port might have a 64 bit buffer and a 115Kbaud bitrate. That buffer is a mere 0.6 ms. You need something substantially faster than 25 ms.

Comment: Well, the rationale so far seems fair, but 25ms is like ages. And btw, isn't the thread timeslice about 10ms in windows?

Comment: Also, to what is this COM port attached on the far end? What is the real source of the files? There are certainly delays there too.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is a serial communication over usb, but again, we are talking about a timeout

Comment: Another point: If a reduce the buffer size, and instead of timeing-out the port read all the required bytes, the read operation can take under 1ms, and by increasing it, it can be anything in between. Just when it times out, there is a +25ms more then expected.

Comment: Right, but at that point you're not relying on the kernel to kick off the timeout process after a set amount of time: there's no context-switch, you're not relying on an inaccurate system tick, etc etc

Comment: @canton7 Then I think your last comment about sums it up :). Thanks everybody for your time! It was a very insightful discussion